# Unable to find the path using rest assured java

Tags: java, json, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

Below is my code in that I am trying to set to a value in JSON format:

```json
{"Details": "{\"user\":\"user1\",\"password\":\"1234\"}"}
```

Here, I have to set the data in user and pass but its in double  quote (`""`).

I have tried a path with `detail.user` but it's not working:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
ObjectNode node = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(new File(templatePath)); 

// System.out.println(node); 

Configuration config = Configuration.builder()
    .jsonProvider(new JacksonJsonNodeJsonProvider())
    .mappingProvider(new JacksonMappingProvider()).build(); 
    
json = JsonPath.using(config).parse(node);

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    String x = list.get(i); 
    arr = x.split(": "); 
    String newHeader = arr[0].replace("|", "."); 
    
    if (newHeader.contains("[")) { 
        String nHeader = "$." + newHeader; 
        String actualVal; 
        if (arr.length >= 2) { 
            actualVal = arr[1]; 
        } else { 
            actualVal = ""; 
        } 
        json.set(nHeader, actualVal).jsonString(); 
    } else { 
        String actualVal; 
        if (arr.length >= 2) { 
            actualVal = arr[1]; 
        } else { 
            actualVal = ""; 
        } 
        json.set(newHeader, actualVal).jsonString(); 
    }
}
```

I have tried with the code above to set the data. But I am getting an `Exception`.

Comment: Your code does not even compile, please provide [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The glaring problem is that the value of `Details` is not an object, but a string (for some reason someone has serialized it twice). Deserialize the string - `"{\"user\":\"user1\",\"password\":\"1234\"}"` a second time to get an object out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Take the following code as reference and try to update your object. You can use gson or jackson to play with the JSON objects. Please do some handful of work before posting a question.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JsonUpdateExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Sample JSON string
    String jsonString = "{\"name\":\"John\", \"age\":25, \"city\":\"New York\"}";

    // Field to update
    String fieldToUpdate = "age";
    
    // New value for the field
    int newValue = 30;

    // Update the JSON
    String updatedJson = updateJsonField(jsonString, fieldToUpdate, newValue);

    // Print the updated JSON
    System.out.println(updatedJson);
}

private static String updateJsonField(String jsonString, String fieldToUpdate, int newValue) {
    try {
        // Create ObjectMapper
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // Read the JSON string into a JsonNode
        JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(jsonString);

        // Update the field
        ((ObjectNode) jsonNode).put(fieldToUpdate, newValue);

        // Convert the updated JsonNode back to a JSON string
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(jsonNode);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return jsonString; // return the original JSON in case of an error
    }
}
}
```